# How to convert timestamp to readable calendar date

Tags: angularjs, cordova, calendar, ionic-framework

I have timestamp date format from hosting database, My problem now is how to convert this timestamp format to readable calendar date and put inside the calendar, the process of converting will be done inside the calendar javascript I think this is possible my problem is how can I do that? I can now translate the to calendar format by using this if I have given declaration of timestamp format.

var timestamp = 1441987200;
          var date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);

```
      datevalues = [
         date.getFullYear(),
         date.getMonth()+1,
         date.getDate(),
         date.getHours(),
         date.getMinutes(),
         date.getSeconds(),
      ];

      alert(datevalues);
```

But I cant put it inside my calendar because of different format of my plugin calendar with this new Date(y, 9, 2).

$scope.events =[ {title: 'Long Event',start: new Date(y, 9, 2),end: new Date(y, 10, 7)}],

Can anyone help me to find the solution for this? Thanks and regards.

Comment: Really not clear what you are asking. What calendar module is it and what is the expected data format.

Comment: I have put to a calendar date in a cordova plugin calendar. But I have problem in format of date because the date data is in timestamp when fetching it form database hosting.

Comment: and in order to put a date in a plugin the format I tried is this format of date start: new Date(y, 9, 2) how about in timestamp format?

Comment: I used this cordova plugin to my ionic app. https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin.

Comment: create date object of timestamp and set to calender method setDate(yourDateObject); it will set your calender to desired date

Comment: can you make an example Sir?

Comment: Did you try using $filter('date') ? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) when you have to handle a lot of times and dates. It's able to parse times in a more convenient way than JavaScript's Date and it's also able to format it just the way you like.

Comment: can you give me a sample as reference?